# Godot: too few arguments

Tags: arguments, godot

every now and then I stumble over an error-message like the one in this case:

```
if "," in text.erase():
print ("comma erased")
```

> error(109,1): Too few arguments for "erase()" call. Expected at least
> 2.

Whatever I try to put into those (), nothing seems to work. How can I find out what arguments I need in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

At least some basic programming knowledge provided, the editor's Search Help offers some useful info in such a case:

```
void erase ( int position, int chars )
Erases chars characters from the string starting from position.
```